# Change shape of div elements and position them to look like a sliced pizza

Tags: css, html

Look at the picture.  It looks like a sliced pizza. Now my question is how to make this thing with divs.

What I am looking for:

1. How to shape divs to look like a pizza slice
2. How to position them into circle

[image: Sliced circle, like a pizza]

EDIT:  Guys, can I do it without border properties? I mean, I want to fill these with content. Any help?

Comment: Show us your code first

Comment: Thank you for reply. However I do not have any code, this is just one idea I got for a future projects. So I am open for any kind of suggestion.

Comment: You can easily (or kinda) make triangular divs. Check here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Also here: http://jsfiddle.net/GR4Kj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only my dad would try to slice a seven slice pizza.  I was the child that ends up with the smaller one.  Basically your pizza has 6 slices of 60 degrees each.  The first part of each slice (without ".pizza") is telling each DIV exactly where to start.  So each one has to be adjusted by increments of 60.  They do not add to each other. The next part (with ".pizza") is how far the slice travels around the curve.  Each slice is 60 there.  All of these values have to add up to 360 total or it could break or overlap.  If you put all the code below in a text file, save it as .html and open it in a browser it should display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS3 Pizza Chart</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
.chart {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
}
.hold {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,100px);
    left:300px;
}
.Pizza {
    position:absolute;
/*  width:100px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
    transform-origin:right center; */
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
    border-radius:100px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
<style>
     .PizzaContainer {
          height: 100px;
          width: 100px;
          float: right;
          margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
     }
     #PizzaSliceYellow .Pizza {
          background-color: #f2cd00;
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceBlue {
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceBlue .Pizza {
          background-color: #002095;
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceRed {
          transform:rotate(120deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceRed .Pizza {
          background-color: #950000;
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
      #PizzaSliceOlive {
          transform:rotate(180deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceOlive .Pizza {
          background-color: #a5a000;
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceOrange {
          transform:rotate(240deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceOrange .Pizza {
          background-color: #f5a010;
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
      #PizzaSliceLime {
          transform:rotate(300deg);
     }
     #PizzaSliceLime .Pizza {
          background-color: #99FF00;
          transform:rotate(60deg);
     }
</style>
<div class="PizzaContainer">
<div class="PizzaBackground"></div>
<div id="PizzaSliceYellow" class="hold">
<div class="Pizza"></div>
</div>
<div id="PizzaSliceBlue" class="hold">
<div class="Pizza"></div>
</div>
<div id="PizzaSliceRed" class="hold">
<div class="Pizza"></div>
</div>
<div id="PizzaSliceOlive" class="hold">
<div class="Pizza"></div>
</div>
<div id="PizzaSliceOrange" class="hold">
<div class="Pizza"></div>
</div>
<div id="PizzaSliceLime" class="hold">
<div class="Pizza"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is sort of what you were looking for? Disclaimer: It is not mine! It is from http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/

**Creating a Drop-Shadowed Circle**

First create a circle with a drop shadow and place it inside of a div so that we can stack additional circles on top of it. The div below has a set height so it stays inline with the content. Just add a border-radius of half the pixel value of the width of a square div.

```css
.pieContainer {
  height: 100px;
}
.pieBackground {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="pieContainer">
  <div class="pieBackground"></div>
</div>
```

**Adding a Slice to the CSS Pie Chart**

Next create a half circle by using clipping. The outer div controls the rotation and then inner div controls the size. Start the outer div at 0 so you only need to edit that for additional slices.

```css
.pieContainer {
  height: 100px;
}
.pieBackground {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
} 
.pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}
.hold {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}
#pieSlice1 .pie {
  background-color: #1b458b;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(50deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(50deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(50deg);
  transform:rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="pieContainer">
  <div class="pieBackground"></div>
  <div id="pieSlice1" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
</div>
```

**Large & Multiple Slices**

For slices over 50% you just need to add another slice that has the same background color.

```css
.pieContainer {
  height: 100px;
}
.pieBackground {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px #000;
} 
.pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}
.hold {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}
#pieSliceBlue .pie {
  background-color: #1b458b;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
#pieSliceBlue2 {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
#pieSliceBlue2 .pie {
  background-color: #1b458b;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(40deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(40deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(40deg);
  transform:rotate(40deg);
}
#pieSliceRed {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(220deg);
  transform:rotate(220deg);
}
#pieSliceRed .pie {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(140deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(140deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(140deg);
  transform:rotate(140deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="pieContainer">
  <div class="pieBackground"></div>
  <div id="pieSliceBlue" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
  <div id="pieSliceBlue2" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
  <div id="pieSliceRed" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
</div>
```

**IE Fallback**
As expected, this doesn’t work in any Internet Explorer browsers below version 9. If you’re concerned about IE users, a simple way to fix this is adding a conditional comment for IE with a jpg of whatever charts you’re trying to display.

Comment: While this is a well-formatted answer, it is a copyright violation and I can't support this. If Kyle Larson is licensing his blog post for reuse, I don't see it.

Comment: Want me to delete it? Or look for reuse license? Sorry about that didn't think it would be a problem at all.

Comment: Yes, I think this should be deleted.

Comment: Ok well before we delete it I did email Kyle to ask permission to use his tutorial especially since I did link it at the top. If he says no then I will be more than ok with taking it away.

Comment: Yes, please try to email author first. I find this comment very useful and it would help others with same problem.

Comment: Got an email back from Kyle, he says its totally fine to use his code and link him all I have to do is replace the text blocks with smaller, changed text so that there is no possible google duplicate penalties.

Comment: Nope, never delete this. The duplicate that was referenced I would not have found without this Q. I searched for pizza, the other is talking about pie charts