# How to increase the size of a div arranged like a pizza without distorting the pizza

Tags: html, css

Using the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30518832/14035443.

I am wondering how to increase the size of the pizza without distorting the pizza. I tried increasing the width and height of the `hold` and the `pizza` as well as adjusting the clip however any adjustments I make distort the pizza. I tried scaling the size of the `hold`, however, it only increases the size of one slice.

HTML & CSS code below:

```css
body {
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .chart {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    
    .hold {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
      left: 300px;
    }
    
    .Pizza {
      position: absolute;
      /*  width:100px;
        height:200px;
        border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
        transform-origin:right center; */
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
      border-radius: 100px;
    }
.PizzaContainer {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      float: right;
      margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceYellow .Pizza {
      background-color: #f2cd00;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceBlue {
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceBlue .Pizza {
      background-color: #002095;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceRed {
      transform: rotate(120deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceRed .Pizza {
      background-color: #950000;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOlive {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOlive .Pizza {
      background-color: #a5a000;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOrange {
      transform: rotate(240deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOrange .Pizza {
      background-color: #f5a010;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceLime {
      transform: rotate(300deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceLime .Pizza {
      background-color: #99FF00;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="PizzaContainer">
    <div class="PizzaBackground"></div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceYellow" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceBlue" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceRed" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOlive" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOrange" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceLime" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the comments of question I understand that the goal of user is to change the whole size of chart so I added that code at the end of answer.

If the goal of you with the phrase **the size of each slice** is that you want to change the percentage of each slice (for example yellow has more space than blue) you can test the code below:

```css
body {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
.chart {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
}
.hold {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,100px);
    left:300px;
}
.Pizza {
    position:absolute;
/*  width:100px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
    transform-origin:right center; */
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
    border-radius:100px; 
}

.PizzaContainer {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      float: right;
      margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
 }
 #PizzaSliceYellow {
      transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceYellow .Pizza {
      background-color: #f2cd00;
      transform:rotate(90deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceBlue {
      transform:rotate(90deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceBlue .Pizza {
      background-color: #002095;
      transform:rotate(30deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceRed {
      transform:rotate(120deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceRed .Pizza {
      background-color: #950000;
      transform:rotate(60deg);
 }
  #PizzaSliceOlive {
      transform:rotate(180deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceOlive .Pizza {
      background-color: #a5a000;
      transform:rotate(60deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceOrange {
      transform:rotate(240deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceOrange .Pizza {
      background-color: #f5a010;
      transform:rotate(60deg);
 }
  #PizzaSliceLime {
      transform:rotate(300deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceLime .Pizza {
      background-color: #99FF00;
      transform:rotate(60deg);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
  <title>pie-chart2</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="PizzaContainer">
    <div class="PizzaBackground"></div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceYellow" class="hold">
    <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceBlue" class="hold">
    <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceRed" class="hold">
    <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOlive" class="hold">
    <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOrange" class="hold">
    <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceLime" class="hold">
    <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You must understand the usage of `transform:rotate(?deg);` in each selector. When we say:

```
#PizzaSliceBlue {
      transform:rotate(90deg);
 }
 #PizzaSliceBlue .Pizza {
      background-color: #002095;
      transform:rotate(30deg);
 }
```

It means that the "Blue slice" will **start** at **90deg** and **continues** until **120deg** (90deg+30deg). So when you want to change the space of each slice you must play with these values, and increase it for one slice and decrease for another one, also change the start point of them to position them correctly.

I added

```
#PizzaSliceYellow {
      transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
```

to the style-sheet for clearing the start point of yellow slice.

But if your goal is to only change the whole size of chart you must change **.hold** and **.Pizza** classes simultaneously like below:

```css
.hold {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    clip:rect(0px,400px,400px,200px);
    left:300px;
}
.Pizza {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    clip:rect(0px,200px,400px,0px);
    border-radius:200px; 
}
```

I changed `width`, `height`, `clip` and `border-radius` proportionally. for example width from 200px to 400px and `clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,100px);` to `clip:rect(0px,400px,400px,200px);`.

Comment: While that's a good solution, I can't help but think of the words in the original question: "I tried scaling the size of the hold, however, it only increases the size of one slice." - I think the user wants to make the whole thing have a larger diameter.

Comment: @enhzflep I could not say that what is the original goal of user. I wanted to help him if the problem is what I understood. maybe the word "one slice" means that only the percentage of one of them is changing and not the other slices.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I want to clarify I want to make the whole pizza larger.

Comment: @hamid-davodi Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To make the whole pizza larger, you could just increase the values, like so:

```css
body {
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .chart {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    
    .hold {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      clip: rect(0px, 500px, 500px, 250px);
      left: 300px;
    }
    
    .Pizza {
      position: absolute;
      /*  width:100px;
        height:200px;
        border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
        transform-origin:right center; */
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      clip: rect(0px, 250px, 500px, 0px);
      border-radius: 250px;
    }
.PizzaContainer {
      height: 250px;
      width: 250
      float: right;
      margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceYellow .Pizza {
      background-color: #f2cd00;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceBlue {
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceBlue .Pizza {
      background-color: #002095;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceRed {
      transform: rotate(120deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceRed .Pizza {
      background-color: #950000;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOlive {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOlive .Pizza {
      background-color: #a5a000;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOrange {
      transform: rotate(240deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOrange .Pizza {
      background-color: #f5a010;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceLime {
      transform: rotate(300deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceLime .Pizza {
      background-color: #99FF00;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="PizzaContainer">
    <div class="PizzaBackground"></div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceYellow" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceBlue" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceRed" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOlive" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOrange" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceLime" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It's also probably a good idea to use something like [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to avoid repeating all those constants. For example:

```css
body {
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      --chart-size: 60px; /* Set this to whatever you want. */
      --chart-half-size: calc(var(--chart-size) / 2);
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .chart {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    
    .hold {
      position: absolute;
      width: var(--chart-size);
      height: var(--chart-size);
      clip: rect(0px, var(--chart-size), var(--chart-size), var(--chart-half-size));
      left: 300px;
    }
    
    .Pizza {
      position: absolute;
      /*  width:100px;
        height:200px;
        border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
        transform-origin:right center; */
      width: var(--chart-size);
      height: var(--chart-size);
      clip: rect(0px, var(--chart-half-size), var(--chart-size), 0px);
      border-radius: var(--chart-half-size);
    }
.PizzaContainer {
      height: var(--chart-half-size);
      width: var(--chart-half-size);
      float: right;
      margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceYellow .Pizza {
      background-color: #f2cd00;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceBlue {
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceBlue .Pizza {
      background-color: #002095;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceRed {
      transform: rotate(120deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceRed .Pizza {
      background-color: #950000;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOlive {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOlive .Pizza {
      background-color: #a5a000;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOrange {
      transform: rotate(240deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceOrange .Pizza {
      background-color: #f5a010;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceLime {
      transform: rotate(300deg);
    }
    
    #PizzaSliceLime .Pizza {
      background-color: #99FF00;
      transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="PizzaContainer">
    <div class="PizzaBackground"></div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceYellow" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceBlue" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceRed" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOlive" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceOrange" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PizzaSliceLime" class="hold">
      <div class="Pizza"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```